# Change distro name from system info

Tags: custom-distributions

I want to change the name and logo of ubuntu 11.10 from system settings -> system info, how do i do that? and make it remain that way even after upgrades to like 12.04?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It could make diagnosing problems confusing.

Comment: How can that make diagnosing problems confusing? just changing the name and logo from system settings -> system info?

Comment: I understand that the name comes from the command lsb_release, which could confuse someone trying to help you. But I am still awfully curious as to why you would want such a thing! (I would imagine it is possible, but I don't know how.)

Comment: just like that, like linux mint did. i am creating my own custom distribution based on ubuntu

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/254327/ubuntu-says-13-04-but-lsb-release-says-12-10 - The excellent answer from @pablomme explains where this information comes from.

Answer (score 4):

```
gksu gedit /etc/*release
```

change it in your risk ,it may crash your system