# Unable to install latest NodeJS version on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, nodejs

On my server I have `0.10.25` "I do not need Rea's version, that is "0.10.30" which is the LTS for `nodejs`, however developers asking to install 4th version, after digging a little bit, I have found that `0.12` it the same `nodejs` merged with some other packages.

There is no package source for `0.12`, I have downloaded `.tar.gz` files form nodejs's website, unpacked, but it does not contain any installation script, moving files manually or creating links is not the way I wish to go, what can I do?

Update:

```
[web01]~> nodejs -v
v0.10.25
[web01]~> apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
[web01]~> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
[web01]~> apt-get install -y nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
[web01]~> uname -a
Linux web01.example.lab 3.19.0-28-generic #30~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 1 09:32:55 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[web01]~>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing the latest Node.js / MongoDB?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/328681/installing-the-latest-node-js-mongodb) See user's answer for instructions for installing node.js 0.12..

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way to install NodeJS is using the official PPA (which contain  the latest version (8.X at the time of this edit).

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

1. Remove current NodeJS installation

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge nodejs*
   ```
2. Install `curl`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install curl
   ```
3. Install NodeJS:

   ```
   curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
   sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
   ```

---

If you absolutely need 0.12 and not 4.1.1 version, run :

3. Install NodeJS:

   ```
   curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
   sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
   ```

Comment: This will not help, see the update in question.

Comment: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Worked for me only after I changed distro name of my Ubuntu, which previously was LinuxMint. When I tried to install for the first time, I got error `## Your distribution, identified as "petra", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support`. Fixed by changing distro release info as described here http://askubuntu.com/questions/115429/change-distro-name-from-system-info

Comment: You should add `-E` before `bash` at the end of the `curl` command...

Answer (score 0):

For linux users the latest version for node.js can be found here

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

Node.js v19.x:

Using Ubuntu

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Using Debian, as root

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | bash - &&\
apt-get install -y nodejs
```